# What exactly happening in this program specifically in the return statement?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

The actual operation is performed in the line return

```
return (num == 1 ? 1 : num * firstFactorial(num - 1 ) );
```

How we get **40320** for num **8**?

```
public class Factorial    {
    public static int firstFactorial(int num)   {
        return (num == 1 ? 1 : num * firstFactorial(num - 1 ) );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println(firstFactorial(8));
    }    
}
```

Comment: read about recursion ... or just listen to the teacher. It's not that difficult, just use pen and paper to understand the basics of recursion

Comment: Use a debugger and step through it.

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Factorial.html
1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 x 7 x 8 = guess what...40320 !

Comment: instead of returning a value from the function, if the condition matches, then a new call is performed and registered into the call stack. Same again  and again if the condition is fulfilled during the sub-calls. Actually the final return value will be a sum of all the return values.. Mathematical series like the factorials are the best to illustrate the recursive behaviour, that s why this one is the most famous one.

Comment: This code is not helped by the use of a conditional operator. Expanding it to if/else would be a lot clearer if you haven't seen code like this before.

Comment: It seems it could use a bit of improvement. If firstFactorial() is called with a value 0 or smaller then it never completes.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things happening in that return statement. One could rewrite the `firstFactorial` function like this:

```
public static int firstFactorial(int num) {
    if (num == 1) {
       return 1;
    }

    int decreased          = num - 1;
    int recursiveFactorial = firstFactorial(decreased);
    int result             = num * recursiveFactorial;

    return result;
}
```

First of all this is using a technique called *recursion*. The function is calling itself with the number parameter decreased by one. You can think of it like this:

```
1. You call firstFactorial with value of 8
2. firstFactorial(8) calls itself with a value of 7
3. firstFactorial(7) calls itself with a value of 6
...
8. firstFactorial(2) calls itself with a value of 1
9. firstFactorial(1) returns 1 because of the if-statement
```

After calling itself the function multiplies the return value of the recursive call with its own parameter and returns it. So it will go on like this:

```
10. firstFactorial(2) multiplies 1 with 2 and returns 2
11. firstFactorial(3) multiplies 2 with 3 and returns 6
10. firstFactorial(4) multiplies 6 with 4 and returns 24
...
14. firstFactorial(8) multiplies 5040 with 8 and returns 40320 to you
```

All together this will calculate the faculty of the value like this: 8 * 7 * 6 * ... * 1

The rest is more or less coding style and syntactic sugar.
You don't need local variables and perform the call and the operations in one line:

```
public static int firstFactorial(int num) {
    if (num == 1) {
       return 1;
    }

    return num * firstFactorial(num -1);
}
```

Then there is the ternary conditional operator in java (`<cond> ? <true statement> : <false statement>`) which allows you to express the whole function body in one line:

```
public static int firstFactorial(int num) {
    if (num == 1) {
       return 1;
    }

    return (num == 1) ? 1 : (num * firstFactorial(num -1));
}
```